# jq: output json array of objects to array of keys with objects

Tags: json, bash, jq

Im looking to reformat some json using jq instead of using Python. I have the following json array of objects. I am looking to change this to an array of keys. The values of the keys should be the object.

```
[{
        "repo_expire": "21,600 second(s) (last: Tue Nov 20 07:14:05 2018)",
        "repo_url": "http://repos.blah.com/CentOS/dev/6/os/x86_64/",
        "repo_tstsync": 0,
        "repo_id": "base",
        "repo_pkgs": "6,713",
        "repo_prdsync": 0,
        "repo_revision": 1530286202,
        "repo_name": "CentOS-6 - Base",
        "repo_size": "5.5 G",
        "repo_updated": "Fri Jun 29 08:37:23 2018"
    },
    {
        "repo_expire": "21,600 second(s) (last: Tue Nov 20 07:36:50 2018)",
        "repo_url": "http://blah.com/epel/dev/6/x86_64/",
        "repo_tstsync": 0,
        "repo_id": "epel",
        "repo_pkgs": "12,448",
        "repo_prdsync": 699,
        "repo_revision": 1542329363,
        "repo_name": "Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64",
        "repo_size": "11 G",
        "repo_updated": "Thu Nov 15 17:50:18 2018"
    },
    {
        "repo_expire": "21,600 second(s) (last: Tue Nov 20 07:44:05 2018)",
        "repo_url": "http://blah.com/CentOS/dev/6/extras/x86_64/",
        "repo_tstsync": "null",
        "repo_id": "extras",
        "repo_pkgs": 33,
        "repo_prdsync": "null",
        "repo_revision": 1537445728,
        "repo_name": "CentOS-6 - Extras",
        "repo_size": "12 M",
        "repo_updated": "Thu Sep 20 05:15:29 2018"
    }
]
```

The following is the desired output.

```
{
    "repos": [{
        "CentOS-6 - Base": {
            "repo_expire": "21,600 second(s) (last: Tue Nov 20 01:14:05 2018)",
            "repo_url": "http://blah.com/CentOS/dev/6/os/x86_64/",
            "repo_tstsync": 0,
            "repo_id": "base",
            "repo_pkgs": "6,713",
            "repo_prdsync": 0,
            "repo_revision": 1530286202,
            "repo_size": "5.5 G",
            "repo_updated": "Fri Jun 29 08:37:23 2018"
        },
        "Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64": {
            "repo_expire": "21,600 second(s) (last: Tue Nov 20 01:36:50 2018)",
            "repo_url": "http://blah.com/epel/dev/6/x86_64/",
            "repo_tstsync": 0,
            "repo_id": "epel",
            "repo_pkgs": "12,448",
            "repo_prdsync": 699,
            "repo_revision": 1542329363,
            "repo_size": "11 G",
            "repo_updated": "Thu Nov 15 17:50:18 2018"
        },
        "CentOS-6 - Extras": {
            "repo_expire": "21,600 second(s) (last: Tue Nov 20 01:44:05 2018)",
            "repo_url": "http://blah.com/CentOS/dev/6/extras/x86_64/",
            "repo_tstsync": "null",
            "repo_id": "extras",
            "repo_pkgs": 33,
            "repo_prdsync": "null",
            "repo_revision": 1537445728,
            "repo_size": "12 M",
            "repo_updated": "Thu Sep 20 05:15:29 2018"
        }
    }]
}
```

I'd need to grab the value of the repo_name key from each object somehow. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following filter produces results in the desired format, but the output marked in the Q as "desired" does not exactly match the given input, which I take to be an oversight.

```
{repos: map( {(.repo_name): del(.repo_name)} )}
```

Comment: That's great! I wasn't even close on my path.

[to_entries[] | .value.repo_id ]

Thank you. Ill select your answer as soon as it lets me.